# Are there standard names for different types of data reports?

Tags: database, format, report, standards, naming

The specific answer I am looking for is a reference to some kind of established standard (with naming conventions) for different report layouts that would be produced from data out of a database. I am hoping to find "context independent" names here - i.e not tied to one particular database type or language.

I understand that there are general distinctions between tabular and graphical types of reports, but I am looking for descriptive terms for particular report types (if that even exists).

I'm sure Google would provide the answer, but I don't quite know what to ask it...

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no 'global' or 'universal' standard; it tends to be heavily organizationally dependant.  [This is an example of the accepted reports for Pearsons.](http://wps.pearsoncustom.com/pls_1256647969_pwo/217/55689/14256538.cw/index.html)

Since report types seem to be subjective, this is a more generic definition of several
[kinds of reports.](http://www.sapdesignguild.org/editions/edition2/willenborg_e/types.html)